# In Google Analytics, can I set the value of page to an arbitrary string?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When setting the page in Google Analytics, can I set the value to an arbitrary string? (in other words, one that's **not** a valid url), like:

```
ga('set', 'page', 'the homepage');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can (the field is a string) and the syntax used is correct: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages

Then you need to send the page with `send` command:

```
ga('set', 'page', 'the homepage');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```